# NPM: make package.json work under both Unix (Mac OSX) and Windows

Tags: json, windows, node.js, unix

I've gotten some NPM package from a third party who is developing under Mac OSX. Their build can split into either development or production using "scripts" object in package.json. For example:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=dev node make.js --build",
    "build-prod": "NODE_ENV=prod node make.js --build",
  }
```

Under Unix, one can run either "npm run build" or "npm run build-prod" to build either directory (naturally, there are some conditional statements in make.js).
Of course, it does not work under Windows - I had to change the commands similar to this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=dev&& node make.js --build",
    "build-prod": "set NODE_ENV=prod&& node make.js --build",
  }
```

(Please note that it was important **not** to put a space before the '&&' - otherwise the environment variable was created with an extra white space in it which ruined all those comparisons in make.js).

However, I would like to have some universal source tree which would work under either Unix or Windows without editing. Could you please give some ideas on how to conditionally split the build depending on the OS?

Comment: these might be relevant: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2800 and https://www.npmjs.org/package/env-variable

Comment: @alandarev: The second link is interesting, but i'm not sure how to squeeze that into the command under "scripts". I guess I'll need to create two scripts - say, dev-make and prod-make - which will just set the NODE_ENV and invoke the make.
Excuse me for not replying to you directly - with just the initial reputation, I cannot yet reply...

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env and its pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been thinking for a while, but I doubt there is any aesthetic solution using these tools, to get the desired effect.

If you are able to influence the change in `make.js`, I would rather change this file to accept `prod` or `dev` as argument, example: `node make.js --build=dev`. With default value, to ensure backwards compatibility.

Using only npm and not modifying `make.js`, I could think of only running another JavaScript code, which would change environment variable, and then call `make.js`.

That will look something like:

```
"build": "node middleman.js"
```

Middleman.js file could then use [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or another module to set variable and execute `node make.js` file.

If you do not want to create an extra file, you can then embed all the JavaScript inside the package.json using:

```
"build": "node -e 'my code'"
```

Be warned, that running "node -e 'process.env[\'NODE_ENV\']=\'dev\' && node make.js" will not work, as `process.env` sets variable in local process, not global (i.e. does not export to the system).

---

Not the direct solution, but for sake of best practices, make it work different.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, letting those switches accept values and slightly changing make.js looks like the most elegant solution. I can communicate that to the package developers - we have a good connection.

Answer (score 10):

The question is pretty old, but for these who faces the problem nowadays, *npm* starting from version >=5.1.0 supports setting shell for processing scripts. By default on Windows, npm internally uses cmd.exe for running scripts, even if npm command itself is typed in git-bash. After setting git-bash as shell, scripts that use bash syntax work normally on Windows:

`npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

Here one needs to substitute his correct path to git-bash executable.

Comment: Works perfectly! This answer deserves to be the correct answer as it solves the issue without additional libs.